# Rails: trouble including modules via a plugin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, plugins, module

I'm trying to create a rails plugin and the problem I'm facing is that the app won't include my modules when migrating the plugin.

Here's what I have so far:
1. A file `lib/patch/settings_helper_patch.rb` with extension code
2. An `init.rb` file with `require_dependency 'patch/settings_helper_patch'`
3. Some code in `settings_helper_patch.rb` which is as follows:

```
module ValidateIssuePatch
  module Patch
    module SettingsHelperPatch
      def self.included(base)
        base.send(:include, InstanceMethods)
      end

      module InstanceMethods
        def issue_options
          #some code here
        end
      end
    end
  end
end

unless SettingsHelper.included_modules.include?(ValidateIssuePatch::Patch::SettingsHelperPatch)
  SettingsHelper.send(:include, ValidateIssuePatch::Patch::SettingsHelperPatch)
end
```

After I migrate the plugin, I wish to use the `issue_options` method, but I get `undefined local variable or method` error.

If I run `SettingsHelper.included_modules.include?(ValidateIssuePatch::Patch::SettingsHelperPatch)` from the console, I get `uninitialized constant Patch::SettingsHelperPatch`.
However, if I call ValidateIssuePatch from the console, I get `=> ValidateIssuePatch` in response.

Can anyone tell me what is the magic I'm missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, if your module is only going to have instance methods, I would recommend using the following easy-to-follow syntax:

```
module ValidateIssuePatch
  module Patch
    module SettingsHelperPatch
      def issue_options
        # code
      end
    end
  end
end

SettingsHelper.include(ValidateIssuePatch::Patch::SettingsHelperPatch)
```

Secondly, the reason why `ValidateIssuePatch` might be defined is that some other file has it which is being required properly. This file isn't being executed in any way. I would raise an error somewhere that, when raised, will verify that the code is / isn't being executed. Something like the following:

```
module ValidateIssuePatch
  module Patch
    module SettingsHelperPatch
      raise "All good" # remove this afterwards

      def issue_options
        # code
      end
    end
  end
end

SettingsHelper.include(ValidateIssuePatch::Patch::SettingsHelperPatch)
```

Chances are that the error won't be raised and it'll confirm that your file isn't being required - either not at all or not in the right order.

To further verify this, simply open up your console and do the following with your existing code:

```
ValidateIssuePatch::Patch::SettingsHelperPatch #=> error
require path_of_file
ValidateIssuePatch::Patch::SettingsHelperPatch #=> no more error
```

Finally, why do you check for the module already being included in `SettingsHelper`? (referring to the `unless` condition) Your code should be including the module only once, not "maybe only once".

Comment: You were right, the file wasn't required. There was another plugin with its own `lib/patch/settings_helper_patch.rb` and only that file was required. I'd never expect that there may be conflicts in file naming between *different* plugins. Solved by moving my file to `lib/validate_issues/patch/settings_helper_patch.rb`